# Can't connect to mysql Laravel-forge

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, forge

I've just purchased a subscription atnforge for 10 dollars/month.

But when I want to connect to mydatabase (mysql),
it's telling me:

> Connected to host, but unable to connect to database forge.
>
> Be sure that the database exists and that you have the necessary
>   privileges.
>
> MySQL said: Unknown database 'forge'

I have an email from forge with my login information. I can ssh into my server. I've also set my ssh key on my mac.

What am I doing wrong? Here a pic with my info:

[image]

EDIT:

Also when I deploy from github I receive this error message:

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

But yesterday it worked! Now it doesn't?

EDIT:

ERROR LOG:

```
From github.com:
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
> php artisan optimize
Generating optimized class loader
Compiling common classes


  [PDOException]                                                                          
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Comment: What if you don't specify the database, can you login? Also, are you sure that you're using the proper password? I don't use Forge, but usually when you login to your server via SSH, it will tell you the MySQL password.

Comment: hmm I created a new ssh key and now it works. But still have the deploy problem? Any idea?

Comment: please see my edit for the error log.

Comment: Never mind made a new question about it.